# How to use laravel Models/Repositories with native php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a website which is built using native php but to speed up the development i have installed laravel in sub directory called  ***new***  , where im using all the laravel features and serving the new pages as 
**mywebsite.com/new/any-laravel-route**.

I want to use the laravel Models/Repositories outside of laravel container with native php by requiring the minimum amount of files to bootstrap the laravel.

I'm using following code to initialize laravel

```
require 'new/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once 'new/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');
$kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

its working quite slow considering the already included files of native platform code as well.

What im looking for is

- Use laravel features with native php
- Laravel should not handle HTTP request (as its doing with the above code)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/illuminate/database

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `$app` variable in place you should be ready to use Laravel service container.

If you can do `$model = $app->make('App\YourModelClass');` you can use it as model.

Comment: Hi , I have tried this approach but it throws 'Reflection Exception' with message 'Class config does not exists'

Comment: I have googled that and it seems related to a mis-configured .env file, may that be the case?

Comment: Hi , i did too but same .env works fine with laravel but initializing the laravel outside causes this exception , STRANGE :(